# Kotlin Serialization to JSON: How to ignore actual field type

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and even newer to [Kotlin Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) and I am trying to convert a Kotlin data class to JSON. Look at the following sample code:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(JSON.stringify(BaseClass1("abc")))
    println(JSON.stringify(BaseClass2("abc")))
}

@Serializable
data class BaseClass1(
        val a: String
)

@Serializable
data class BaseClass2(
        val a: Any
)
```

The output is:

```
{"a":"abc"}
{"a":["kotlin.String","abc"]}
```

So I save a String in a variable of the type `Any` (which should be perfectly valid). However, this results in the serialized value being an array of the type and the value. This also happens with other classes and subclasses (when I extend the field's type for example).

How can I get `stringify` to always use the value, regardless of the field's actual type? I want the second `stringify` result of the program above to match the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this using a custom serializer.

The only downside is that as I don't save the type, I cannot deserialize the object again, but I only need to serialize in my program.

```
@Serializable
data class BaseClass2(
        @Serializable(with = PlainObjectSerializer::class) val a: Any
)


object PlainObjectSerializer : KSerializer<Any> {
    override val serialClassDesc: KSerialClassDesc
        get() = SerialClassDescImpl("") //PlainObjectDesc

    override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: Any) {
        val saver = serializerByValue(obj, output.context)
        output.writeSerializableValue(saver, obj)
    }

    override fun load(input: KInput): Any {
        throw Exception("This serializer can only be used for serialization!")
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: As @[Nikky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9006779/nikky) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350592/5292296), this code can be further simplified by utilizing the serialization plugin:

```
@Serializer(forClass = BaseClass2::class)
object PlainObjectSerializer : KSerializer<Any> {
    override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: Any) {
        val saver = serializerByValue(obj, output.context)
        output.writeSerializableValue(saver, obj)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you may simplify your solution by annotating the serializer with `@Serializer(forClass=BaseClass1:class)`
then you can leave out the load and serialClassDesc overrides .. the plugin will generate the defaults for you

Comment: Thanks, that saved me a bit of messy code. But I would recommend you to not write this as a whole answer but comment on my answer instead, as it is only supplementary information.

Comment: at the time i was under the required karma to post a answer under anything that was not my solution, tbh a bit backwards,
i am not sure whatwould happen if i deleted my answer now.. so i won't try